# Windows Phone Toolkit namespace/reference not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm going nuts over this...

I can't add Windows Phone Toolkit to my Windows Phone 8.0 project in Visual Studio 2013.

Nothing works.

Using `<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector></toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>` on XAML page dishes out:

*"The name LongListMultiSelector does not exist in clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.C‌​ontrols.Toolkit"*

What I did:

- Installed Toolkit with NuGet version 2.8.5 (so its over 2.1 as required)
- Added `"xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.C‌​ontrols.Toolkit"` to my XAML page
- Deleted Visual Studio cache in %Temp%, restarted VS... Nothing.
- Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit is present in project References...

It seems like VS is not even recognizing that reference. Toolkit Controls are not present on a list of Controls that can be added to "Toolbox" sidebar.

**I desperately need a list with multi selection in my project**, and that Toolkit seems to be the only solution...

Comment: Have you tried to use this `<phone:LongListSelector/>` instead !

Comment: Did you try running the project?  Sometimes Visual Studio will indicate errors like that, which don't exist.

Comment: Chrisophe - LongListSelector has no multi select (Windows Store app ListView has Multi mode).

Comment: McGarnagle - Yep, it happened to me once that VS indicated something missing in XAML that was bullshit ;) But not this time sadly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it... by accident.

I had some other LongListSelector on the same XAML page, with custom ItemDataTemplateSelector, that caused Visual Studio to act strange.

I deleted that LongListSelector (it worked without a problem, so I don't have a slightest idea what was itchy about it for VS) and toolkit reference started to work.

Strange! And so frustrating...